# DNN Extensions fail to load DNN 7.4.2

Tags: paypal, installation, dotnetnuke

My first DNN site.  Please go easy.

I'm trying to load some extensions (Blog & a PayPal extension).

While the admin console show's they're installed I can't see them or start them.  They are not evident on any of the menus.

The theme creators say its not their problem.

Any suggestions for a Newby on how to get the extensions working?

thanks

Comment: Are they visibly listed on the Host/Extensions page?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to go to the page where you want a module to live and then use the Modules admin menu entry to Add New Module to the page.  Click the menu entry, and you can drag and drop a module onto the page.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the concept and can follow the various menus and find the extension I wish to add.  However all that happens after I click the "Add" button is that empty 'banner' sections are added to the page.  (Even though 'banners' were not selected)

Comment: I don't understand the "Banner" comment.  What module(s) do you think you added to the page?  And, are you in Edit mode?

Comment: Image below Joe.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

They're listed and "In Use" is recorded OS "No"

Comment: You are on the Admin page, and it certainly looks like you have added two modules to the bottom of the page.  One of them seems to be the Banners module, as the screenshot shows that mousing over the edit pencil icon shows the Banner Options.

Answer (score 0):

OK - here's a screenshot of the Admin Page in Edit Mode whilst loggedon as a Super User after an Extension Module has been added to the page.

As you can see:

1. The extensions are not showing
2. Instead the area on the page shows 'Banner Options' even though no banners were inserted.

[image: DNN Extensions Image shows Banner options instead]

Answer (score 0):

You are on the Admin page, and it certainly looks like you have added two modules to the bottom of the page.  One of them seems to be the Banners module, as the screenshot shows that mousing over the edit pencil icon shows the Banner Options.

My guess is that this isn't close to what you want to do.

I think that what you want to do is to add a module or modules to some other pages.

So, go to the page to which you want to add a module.  Then, click or mouseover the Modules menu item in the admin menu.  Select a module and add it to the page.

Does that make more sense?